# cmake: GNUInstallDirs variable differs before installation

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I have a cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(APP_NAME "vihoman")
project(${APP_NAME} VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C)
include( GNUInstallDirs )


set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(TARGET tgt PROPERTY C_STANDARD 11)

add_definitions(-DTEMP_PATH="${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${APP_NAME}/templates/")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c manage.c disassembly.c error.c manage/helpers.c manage/templateman.c manage/hostman.c)
add_executable(${APP_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

install(DIRECTORY templates DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/${APP_NAME})
install(TARGETS ${APP_NAME}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION
        ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)
```

Variable DTEMP_PATH is used in the code.

```
#ifdef TEMP_PATH
    #define TEMP_FOLDER TEMP_PATH
#endif
```

When I install the program, the templates folder is formed under the path `/usr/local/share/vihoman/`. But DTEMP_PATH is `share/vihoman/`. Why does this happen if logically there must be the same paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any other `CMAKE_INSTALL_<dir>` variable, which is set by [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) module, the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR` could contain a **relative** path.

It is perfectly allowed to use this variable in the DESTINATION option for [install](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/install.html) command, because relative values of this option are treated relative to the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, which is `/usr/local` by default.

If you want an **absolute** path, then use `CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_<dir>` kind of variable instead:

```
add_definitions(-DTEMP_PATH="${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_DATADIR}/${APP_NAME}/templates/")
```

Comment: On the local machine it worked, when I upload to ppa / repositories, DTEMP_PATH writes /build/vihoman-9Jl4BL/vihoman-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/share/vihoman/templates/ I understand correctly that in this case only a strict path will help ?

Comment: It seems that on ppa someone sets `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to `/build/vihoman-9Jl4BL/vihoman-1.1/debian/tmp/usr`, assuming it to be `/usr`, which will be moved from `/build/vihoman-9Jl4BL/vihoman-1.1/debian/tmp/` into normal root (`/`). Instead, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` should be `/usr` (as on the target machine), and installation could be performed with `make DESTDIR=/build/vihoman-9Jl4BL/vihoman-1.1/debian/tmp/`.